# Importing CSV data from UN database

Tags: r, csv, read.table, read.csv

I'm trying to import refugee data from the UNHCR http://popstats.unhcr.org/en/time_series

I export the data and try to import it using the `read.csv` function which I've never had problems using before and receive the following error code

```
un <- read.csv("un.csv", na.strings = "..")
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

for ref I've opened the csv file in word and this is the format it is in;

```
""Extracted from the UNHCR Population Statistics Reference Database","United Nations High Commissioner for Refugees"
"Date extracted: 2015-09-18 04:37:24 +02:00"

Year,"Country / territory of asylum/residence",Origin,"Population type",Value
1951,Australia,Various/Unknown,"Refugees (incl. refugee-like situations)",180000
1951,Austria,Various/Unknown,"Refugees (incl. refugee-like situations)",282000
1951,Belgium,Various/Unknown,"Refugees (incl. refugee-like situations)",55000
1951,Canada,Various/Unknown,"Refugees (incl. refugee-like situations)",168511
1951,Switzerland,Various/Unknown,"Refugees (incl. refugee-like situations)"
```

and so appears to be in the correct format so I'm at a bit of a loss as to what's going wrong.

Thanks for your help

Chris

Comment: You need to skip the first line, which indeed has four columns while your data has five columns. See `?read.csv` for how.

Comment: okay this has worked for me, thank you very much, I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your data have typos. It should be like:

```
un = structure(list(Year = c(1951L, 1951L, 1951L, 1951L, 1951L), Country...territory.of.asylum.residence = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Australia", 
"Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Switzerland"), class = "factor"), 
    Origin = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Various/Unknown", class = "factor"), 
    Population.type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Refugees (incl. refugee-like situations)", class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(180000, 282000, 55000, 168511, NA)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Country...territory.of.asylum.residence", "Origin", "Population.type", 
"Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Then you could import easily using **read.table()**:

```
df=read.table("un.csv", header = T, sep=",")
```